# Support the glGenerateMipmap() function in OpenGl ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0, android-mipmap

In the [Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) documentation support for the glGenerateMipmap(GLenum target) function starts with OpenGL 3.0. Why then does this function also exist in the GLES20 class?:

```
GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Or does OpenGL ES 2.0 also support the automatic generation of mipmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page where you refer to, is not a specification, it is a wiki. Further more you refer to the [*desktop* OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) pages rather than the [OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php) pages.
The [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) OpenGL ES page, clearly states that `glGenerateMipmap` is provides since OpenGL ES 2.0.
Anyway, the only truth is the OpenGL (ES) specification.

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 Full Specification- 3.7.11 Mipmap Generation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf#page=93&zoom=100,168,814):

> Mipmaps can be generated with the command
>
> ```
> void GenerateMipmap( enum target );
> ```

Comment: I also read in a book about support for this function since OpenGL ES 3.0. Therefore, such doubts arose. Thank you very much for your answer and link!